# Flutter Navigation bug issue

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have 4 page to navigate:
**A > B > C > D**

I use Navigator.pushReplacement for navigate from each page.
The problem is every first time run the app from vscode, when C > D it will be freeze and then I close the app from emulator and open it again (not re-run from vscode). It works well. Is this danger? what should I fix to make the app run smooth

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => Nextpages()),
        );
```

Comment: Get.to(Nextpages());  try using getx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for the help. Apparently, it's my fault. The navigator pushes the replacement method just fine, but I forgot to dispose of all controllers. So it calls an event but unfortunately, the page is closed, which causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the correct way.

**Route:**

```
        // A modal route that replaces the entire screen with a platform-adaptive transition.
        final MaterialPageRoute<dynamic> route = MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return const ScreenA(); // ScreenB or ScreenC or ScreenD
          },
        );
```

**Push:**

```
        // Push the given route onto the navigator.
        await Navigator.of(context).push(route);
```

**Pop:**

```
        // Pop the top-most route off the navigator.
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
```